# Power BI: Is it possible to show the first value in my continiuous x-axis in a line chart?

Tags: powerbi

Hello I have a line chart that looks like so:

[line chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiS6l.png)

My x-axis has got the Type "Continuous". Now I would love my x-axis to also show the first year in my data. In my case 1972. Do you have any idea how this could work?

Comment: There is no option to display x axis starting and ending values. We need to think some workaround